# Add Subtitle, Caption and Legend title in Jetbrains' Lets-Plot

Tags: r, kotlin, ggplot2, lets-plot

I've written a plot in Kotlin using https://github.com/JetBrains/lets-plot library. I want to be able to set a title, a subtitle, a caption, and edit (or remove) the legend title.

```
    val goodColors = listOf("#A1DBB2", "#69D2E7")
    val badColors = listOf("#F45D4C", "#F7A541", "#FACA66", "#F45D4C", "#F7A541", "#FACA66")

    val barWidth = 0.4

    return letsPlot() +
            labs(x = "", y = "", title = "My title") +

            geomBar(stat = Stat.identity, position = Pos.stack, color = "black", width = barWidth) {
                x = listOf(1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0).map { it - (barWidth / 2) + barWidth }
                y = listOf(16, 34, 18, 37)
                fill = listOf("Good one", "Good two", "Good one", "Good two")
            } +

            geomBar(stat = Stat.identity, position = Pos.stack, color = "red", width = barWidth) {
                x = listOf(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0).map { it - (barWidth / 2) }
                y = listOf(71, 20, 17, 55, 11, 10)
                fill = listOf("Bad one", "Bad two", "Bad Three", "Bad one", "Bad two", "Bad Three")
            } +

            scaleFillManual(values = goodColors + badColors) +
            scaleXDiscrete(breaks = listOf(1.0, 2.0), labels = listOf("2021-01-01", "2021-02-01")) +
            theme()
```

In ggplot2, I can set the subtitle in `labs()`, `ggtitle()` or `theme()`, but in Lets-plot, these functions don't accept either a subtitle or a caption.

Is there a way to set a subtitle, a caption, and edit or remove the legend title?

[image: Sample output from code above]

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the legend title by setting an empty name for `fill` scale:

```
+ scale_fill_discrete(name="")
```

The situation with subtitle and caption is bad, please follow [#417](https://github.com/JetBrains/lets-plot/issues/417).

UPD: `subtitle` & `caption` were added in [v2.3.0](https://github.com/JetBrains/lets-plot/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#230---2022-03-21).

Comment: `name=""` actually removes the entire legend.
`scaleFillDiscrete(name=" ", labels = labels) +` did the trick for me.